# Unix command to get top 10 from the sorted file names in current directory

Tags: unix, ls

I understand that the command to list alphabetically the file names in current directory is `ls`.

But how can I get top 10 from the sorted file names in current directory?

Comment: A note that ls doesn't sort naturally. So a file that starts with T will show before a file beginning with a.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the command "head" to get the first ten lines:

```
ls | head -10
```

Answer (score 6):

With sorting:

```
ls | sort | head -10
```

A note that ls doesn't sort naturally. So a file that starts with T will show before a file beginning with a.